# How to organize the features export modules

Tags: features

As we go along with features export, its being a mess. What I have been doing so far is every module which have another module that contains the feature exports. Let say their is module 'test' and it has some variable settings and I exported it via features. I will have another module name 'test_features_export' or something like that which contains the component associated with that module. But in some cases, the component can be too generic like 'role' which can be associated with multiple modules. Then its issue to bind to any specific features where it is meaningful.

So my question is , is there any better way to organize the features exports modules ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we usually do, is create Features based on Content Type, and group everything related in there.

So a Content Type News, would be put in a Feature 'MyProject_News'. Together with everthing that is relevant, like Views related to News, pathauto pattern, specific image styles only in use by News content, etc ..
Usually, we also have another Base or General Feature, containing more generic stuff like text format settings, site settings, .. and also our roles. This Base/General Feature, is a dependency in all other Features.

Others split it up differently, with a Feature containing all the Content Types, another to hold all Image Styles, another one for Contexts, etc ..

In the end, it's all up to you. You can organize it any way you wish.
However I do choose the first method, as in my opinion, a Feature should be able to operate on it's own, or being disabled, without messing up anything in the site.